# Как на TypeScript указать тип для фукнции?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, типы

Мне нужно написать на typeScript типы для функции, которая принимает объект config, в свойствах которого записаны функции, а возвращает объект с теме же свойствами что и config, но в значениях записаны результат выполнения функции:

```
function init (config) {
   return Object
            .keys(config)
            .reduce((prev, key)=> 
                    {
                       prev[key] = config[key]()
                       return prev
                     }, {})
}
```

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на TypeScript можно описать тип такой функции?**

*Т.е. функция init как бы будет библиотечная, и другие разработчики, смогут её вызывать, например, вот так:*

```
let temp = init({a:()=>5 as number, b:()=>[3,4] as number[]}).
```

*Тогда в **temp** будет записан объект **{a:5, b:[3,4]}**, и хочется что бы typescript автоматически вывел его (temp) типы, и ругался бы, например, на вызов **temp.a.map()** т.к. в свойстве **'a'** объекта **temp** находится число, а не массив т.к. в параметре функции init в свойстве **'a'** была функция, которая возращает число, следовательно после выполнения функции init там будет число. Хочется понять, как можно указать типы для функции init, что бы это работало...*

Comment: Это зависит от того, какие типы будут возвращать функции. И покажите тип для `config`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, идея такая, что config имеет тип на подобии {[K:string]:()=>any}, а на выходе соотвественно будет тип {[K:string]:any}. Но проблема в any , хочется что бы ts как то выводил тип по тому параметру который я передал. Т.е. если я передам init({test:()=>5}).test.map, то ts вывел бы, что фукнция вернёт объект у которого свойство test - это число, и выдало бы ошибку, что у числа нет свойства map

Comment: Без явного указания типов так не получится, насколько я знаю.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а можно ли как то в ts объявить тип для функции - type TA = () => number; а потом, какой нибудь констукцией указать, что type TB имеет тип, который равен результату выполнения TA . Т.е. что-то в духе 
type TB = TA() . Или так сделать нельзя никак?

Comment: добавь в вопрос больше информации о том где какие типы ожидаются.

Comment: Покажите более подробно, как вы собираетесь использовать это. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте побольше деталей и описаний. Сейчас сложно дать ответ, не до конца понятно, что вы хотите)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, я просто хочу написать функцию init(код функции, указан в вопросе), которая бы принимала объект в свойствах которого записаны функции, а возвращала бы тот же объект, но уже с результатом выполнения этих функций Т.е. пользователь, например, вызовет функцию let temp = init({a:()=>5 as number, b:()=>[3,4] as as number[]}). То в temp будет объект {a:5, b:[3,4]}. И хочется что бы typeScript автоматически вывел типы для этого объекта

Comment: @Grundy , добавил

Comment: функции в config могут возвращать любой тип? или только number и его производные?

Comment: @Grundy , любой.

Comment: тогда похоже никак не сделать. для отдельных функций [можно получить тип который они возвращают](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053162/2881286) но можно ли это как-то к объекту, вроде config в вопросе, применить пока не понятно

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. ReturnType работает. Написал вот так function init<T extends { [k: string]: () => any }>(config: T): {[r in keyof T]:ReturnType<T[r]>} {....} и заработало!

Comment: Фантаститка! Добавьте как ответ к своему вопросу - в будущем может пригодиться многим людям!

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt1, отлично! Напиши ответ с пояснениями :-) Я помнил про `keyof T` но на `T extends` меня уже не хватило :)

Answer (score 1):

Совместными усилиями нашли:

```
function init<T extends { [k: string]: () => any }>(config: T):{[r in keyof T]:ReturnType<T[r]>} {....}
```

И это работает, после вызова, например

```
let temp = init({a:()=>5 as number, b:()=>[3,4] as number[]}).
```

TypeScript автоматически выведет для temp тип {a:number, b:number[]} и срезультатом работы функции можно будет нормально работать.